# Is it possible to have an element inside an input?

Tags: css, html, input, markup

If I have for instance a number input for a price, is it possible to have a span between the value and the up/down arrows to place the $/€/£ symbols?

I guess it can be done with a background-image, but can it be done any other way?

Comment: Can you give an example in JSFiddle?

Comment: Show us the code of what you've tried so we can have a look. The question is a bit too broad at the moment.

Comment: Put the code what u have tried...

Comment: @billy.farroll Clicking the `<>` snippet editor will produce a snippet HERE instead of an external site

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. - In this specific case it was enough to google "currency input"